# How to make gradle jdk docker image accept Self-Signed SSL certificate

Tags: docker, gradle, ssl, docker-compose

I am building a springboot app using gradle for dependency management and docker compose for my CI pipeline. My workbox is running MacOS Ventura

When I attempt to build the application locally with a `gradle build` command everything works as it should; however, I run into what seems like an SSL error when attempting the same command from within a docker-compose file. This seems to be because my company is using Netskope to monitor our network traffic by redirecting our requests with its own self-signed certs, and the docker daemon is unaware of these certs when I attempt to build my app.

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3"
services:
  # Gradle build image
  my-application-gradle-build:
    image: gradle:7.6.4-jdk11
    volumes:
      - .:/home/gradle/project
      - ~/.gradle/gradle.properties:/home/gradle/.gradle/gradle.properties
      - ~/.m2:/home/gradle/.m2
    working_dir: /home/gradle/project
    command: gradle --no-daemon build
```

When uploaded to our CI platform (Bamboo), this command is called the same way by my build job and completes with no errors.

**What I have tried**

1. Copy the cert .pem file to the build context

Attempted 2 ways:

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3"
services:
  # Gradle build image
  my-application-gradle-build:
    image: gradle:7.6.4-jdk11
    volumes:
      - .:/home/gradle/project
      - ~/.gradle/gradle.properties:/home/gradle/.gradle/gradle.properties
      - ~/.m2:/home/gradle/.m2
      - ~/.certs:/Library/Application\ Support/Netskope/STAgent/data/nscacert.pem
```

DOCKERFILE

```
FROM eclipse-temurin:11-jdk-jammy
COPY /Library/Application\\ Support/Netskope/STAgent/data/nscacert.pem /tmp
RUN keytool -import -trustcacerts -file /tmp/nscacert.pem -alias MyCertificate -keystore $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts -storepass changeit -noprompt
EXPOSE 12533
COPY \*.jar my-application.jar
CMD java ${JAVA_OPTS} -jar my-application.jar
```

2. Disable TLS verification using `DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY=0` command line arg
3. Added the following plugin repo definitions to settings.gradle.kts

```
pluginManagement {
  repositories {
    gradlePluginPortal()
    google()
    mavenCentral()
  }
}
dependencyResolutionManagement {
  repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
  repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
  }
}
```

When attempting to run my docker-compose.yml file without the above plugin repo definitions, the build fails on the first dependency it tries to pull (springboot gradle plugin) with the same error found in [this gradle community post](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/gradle-core-plugins-plugin-is-not-in-org-gradle-namespace/44735)

However, when I add the repo definitions to settings.gradle.kts, I am able to see a bunch of failed SSL handshake exceptions with the message:
`javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target`

My suspicion is that I need to somehow configure the jre downloaded by gradle:7.6.4-jdk11 to trust Netskope's self-signed cert, but everything I've tried so far has resulted in the same SSL error

Answer (score 0):

#2: DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY applies only to communication between the docker *client* and docker *daemon*, and not even that when using the default Unix-domain socket; it has no effect on any container or image.

#1B: in Java 9 up the file is `$JAVA_HOME/lib/security/cacerts` (no more `jre`) and your `RUN keytool -importcert` should have given FileNotFoundException and status 1 -- but you don't need to spell it out, because in 9 up you can use *option* `-cacerts` *instead of* `-keystore $correct_file`. However that would only work for your application-run container, not your (stock) gradle, and I presume you need the gradle to build your application before you run it.

*Both* the temurin and gradle images use the __cacert_entrypoint hack, so you can use the same solution for both:

- mount your cert file to /certificates/something.crt (must be that suffix) or a directory containing it (and optionally other cert files but nothing else named *.crt) to /certificates
- in the composefile or --env or --env-file or .env, and dockerfile or run command, set USE_SYSTEM_CA_CERTS=1

PS: the gradle image already *contains* the indicated JDK; it doesn't download anything, and if it did, a JRE wouldn't be sufficient (though for most apps once built you could *run* in temurin:11-jre[-OS])

Comment: I believe I followed your instructions correctly, but am still facing the same error message:

Added the following line to the volume declaration section in docker-compose.yml
`- /Path/To/Certificate/netskope_certificate.crt:/certificates/netskope_cert.crt
` and ran with the following command: `docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml run -e USE_SYSTEM_CA_CERTS=1 --rm -T my-application-gradle-build`.

Comment: Possibly also worth noting, since the cert was originally in .pem format I converted it to a .crt file with the following command first: `openssl x509 -outform der -in nscacert.pem -out netskope_certificate.crt`

Comment: .crt is a content/purpose not a format and can be either DER or PEM in general, and `keytool -import` can read either so there's no need to convert when using that, but .crt files _for Debian-family update-ca-certificates_ MUST be PEM.

Comment: That did it! Didn't work in .pem format; however, the final solution was, instead of using the openssl command above, a simple `cp nscacert.pem nscacert.crt` to rename the file extension. The steps I described above all worked after that. This has been bugging me for over a year- thank you SO much